# Use one version of java library or another => make code compatible for both

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm working on a Spring Boot project built with Gradle and the main language is Kotlin.
In this project, there is one imported library (developed in Java) which, depending on the version I use, has 5 or 6 parameters in the constructor of a specific class I use.

For now, I switch between the versions manually by changing the version number in the build.gradle.kts file so my question would be : regardless of the version I use, how could my code work for all the versions ?

So, basically,

library-version1.jar => Class(6 parameters)
library-version2.jar => Class(5 parameters)

project with library-version1.jar or library-version2.jar imported => universal code to create instance of Class

P.S : may I add that I have to use those 2 versions of the library.

Comment: I think challenging the requirement that you use two different library versions is likely to lead to less pain in the long term than trying to cope with both.  After all, this extra constructor param isn't the only difference between the two, is it?  And other differences may cause bugs that the compiler won't spot.

Comment: Indeed. This sounds like a terrible approach.

Comment: @gidds  Would it be possible from the build.gradle.kts to have as an output 2 versions of the app, depending on the version of the used library ?

Comment: @DanielJacob If you can answer this question, feel free to do it too :)

Comment: Could you have two separate versions of your project, one for each version of the library?  (Or split your project into a dependent part and an independent part, and have two separate versions of the dependent part?)

Comment: @gidds I forgot to mention : I solved my initial question by using reflection. The question I asked in the comment is a follow-up. To answer your question, yes, I'd like to have 2 separate versions of my app (depending on the version of the dependency) but is it possible to do that just with the build.gradle.kts file ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my initial question :

```
val yourVariable = YourClass::class.java
val constructor = yourVariable.constructors[0] //The class I use has only one constructor
val implementationVersion = yourVariable.`package`.implementationVersion
if (implementationVersion < "a specific version number") {
     constructor.newInstance(6 parameters) as YourClass
} else {
  constructor.newInstance(5 parameters) as YourClass
}
```

But now I have a follow-up question that you can find in the comments (I can still post it here though) :

In my build.gradle.kts file, I have this line in my dependencies :

```
dependencies {
   implementation("myLibrary:1.0")
   ...
}
```

Obviously, I don't want to switch between myLibrary v1 and v2 manually. Just by changing the build.gradle.kts file, would it be possible to have :

```
build.gradle.kts -> appV1 (if myLibrary v1 used)
                 -> appV2 (if myLibrary v2 used)
```

?